# unable to write data in sql database by java but reading successfully

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, jdbc-odbc, mssql-jdbc

**I'm using the code below:**

```
JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        try{
        String query = "Insert Into check(Name, Password)Values(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
        pst.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
/*      pst.setString(3, textField_2.getText());
        pst.setString(4, textField_4.getText());
        pst.setString(5, textField_5.getText());
        */

        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");
        pst.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

I am retrieving data from a SQL database, but whenever I try to insert data,  I get errors during runtime:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'check'.     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)   at
>   AdminPanel$2.actionPerformed(AdminPanel.java:184)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run (Unknown Source)

Comment: try adding a space before `values`

Comment: Try adding a semicolon at the end of the sql statement.                                                          

String query = "Insert Into check(Name, Password)Values(?,?);";

Comment: Still getting same error log. tried both of your suggestions bro

Comment: Can 'check' be a word that can't be used in the sqls, may be a reserved word? Instead of 'check' try 'abc' and see if you get same error...

Comment: Seems like deepakl is right. Its a sql keyword to put constraints.

Comment: thanks deepakl it worked, i just changed table name from check

Comment: Yes, correct, it is a keyword for putting constraint, thanks Kalhara for confirming that and you are welcome Kamran...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'check' is a reserved keyword and so code is failing, trying with a name which is not a keyword should solve the issue.

Comment: Using `INSERT INTO [check] ( ...` would also fix the problem without having to change the table name.